# login with API. yii2

Tags: php, api, yii2

I need to use the API to login. API to send `$ _POST [ 'username']`, `$ _POST [ 'password']` on `actionLogin ()`.

```
public function actionLogin()
{
if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
    $this->redirect($this->createUrl('site/_allorders'));
$model = new LoginForm;
if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
    if ($model->validate()) {
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }
}
$this->layout = 'mini';
$this->render('_loginForm', array('model' => $model));
}
```

method `$ model-> validate ()` normally passes, but it is impossible to log in. What is my fault or what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

you need to login method in LoginForm class ,have'nt you login method ?!

```
  public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and used in login action :

```
  public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        $this->redirect($this->createUrl('site/_allorders'));
    $model = new LoginForm;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }

    $this->layout = 'mini';
    $this->render('_loginForm', array('model' => $model));
}
```

if you join yii2 recently ,please tested advance yii2 project is [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md)
.it have login api

Comment: When I get command with API the session doesn't work, when I do it from its form , it works.